# Getting NSArrayController item for right click in NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to create a file explorer using nscollectionview and am currently implementing a right click menu for each item (i.e. copy/delete/rename/etc). I currently have:

- An NSCollectionView linked with an NSArrayController which holds a custom object
- A subclass of NSBox as the view for each item, this also tracks mouse events and passes them to the controller
- The controller has an NSMenu outlet (rcMenu) and also an NSView outlet (itemView) for the NSBox subclass that should be where the menu popup
- The code for calling the menu is:

  [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:rcMenu withEvent:event forView:itemView];

Once run, this works in that the menu pops up when right clicking the item in the collection view, but on inspecting the event that's passed to the controller, there's not really anything I could use to find out which item was right clicked other than the x,y coordinates (which seem to be for the NSWindow rather than the item or NSCollectionView). What I really want is the object in the NSArrayController that had it's view right clicked.

Is this down to me setting it up incorrectly, is there an easy way to figure it out, or is it just that tough to work it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try setting the menu of each collection view item's view. Most likely, you'll do this by overriding `+defaultMenu` in your item view class. Once you do that, comment out the `popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:` message and see whether you can get away without it.

Furthermore, it would then not be too hard to serve up different menus for different kinds of items (e.g., folders vs. packages vs. files, and different types of files at that). You'd probably have to override `-menuForEvent:` instead of `+defaultMenu`.

Comment: Will the method of getting the menu up affect my ability to get the item from the array controller though? This is the real problem I'm having.

For what it's worth I tried the defaultMenu and that worked, but had issues trying to get menuForEvent to return rcMenu, though it returned one created by code fine.

Comment: “Get the item from the array controller”? You'll already know which represented object the user clicked on by which item view they clicked on, presuming you have a reference from your item view back to either the collection view item or the represented object.

Comment: I think that's the issue, I can't figure out how to get that reference between the itemview and the actual item/represented object.

Comment: You add it yourself. You declare a property for it in your item view class, and the code that instantiates the class then sets the property on each new instance.

Comment: OK, I've gotten that sorted. The line I was looking for was:
  [self bind:@"track" toObject:item withKeyPath:@"representedObject" options:nil];

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm having similar issues with NSCollectionView.  Could you tell me where you put that [self bind: code and what type is variable track?

Comment: My guess is that it's a custom property of their controller, which they've exposed as a binding.

Answer (score 1):

I found an other solution that might help.

For this solution I made a subclass of NSCollectionViewItem and NSView, respectively (and for the ease of explaining) `ItemViewController` and `ItemView`.

I'm assuming you work with IB where you have already bound your NSCollectionView to the ContentArray of your NSArrayController (also bind the selectionIndexes).

Next add an ViewController object to the NIB and make sure its custom class is set to the `ItemViewController`. Now connect it to the itemPrototype outlet of your NSCollectionView.

Next add a Custom View object to the NIB and set its custom class to `ItemView`. Connect its outlet to the view property of your `ItemViewController`.

In the interface file of `ItemView` create a representedObject-like property. With this I mean something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id someRepresentedObjectPropertyName
```

This will be the property which will represent the item in your NSArrayController.
Now go to the implementation file of `ItemViewController` and override the `-setRepresentedObject:` method. In here we will first let the `ItemViewController` handle setting its representedObject, afterwards we assign the same representedObject to the property we made in `ItemView`. The override would look like:

```
-(void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];

    //Do some appropiate checking on the representedObject...

    if (self.view != nil) {
        [(ItemView *)self.view setSomeRepresentedObjectPropertyName:self.representedObject];
    }
}
```

Now if you go back to the implementation of `ItemView` you can override the method `-rightMouseUp:` and build/set-up a NSMenu there and use the `-popUpMenuPositioning...:` method. The `someRepresentedObjectPropertyName` property of `ItemView` should be set to the correct item in your NSArrayController.

**EDIT:**

Instead of overriding `-setRepresentedObject` you could also bind the `ItemView`'s `someRepresentedObjectPropertyName` to `representedObject.someRepresentedObjectPropertyName`

Comment: You could avoid part with overriding `setRepresentedObject` by using bindings from code (I mean bind view's `SomeRepresentedObjectPropertyName` to `representedObject.someRepresentedObjectPropertyName`)

Comment: I agree, you could avoid the override-part with bindings. I'll update my answer with your suggestion